# HTTP GET Encoding for Web Service Calls

Tags: c#, python, http, get

I have a web service that I'm calling from C#.  I've been able to successfully get a response using simple GET queries, such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/py-wps.cgi?service=wps&version=1.0.0&request=describeprocess&identifier=test
```

However, when make more complex queries the response is always an error.

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/py-wps.cgi?service=wps&version=1.0.0&request=execute&identifier=test&datainputs=[key1=val1,val2,val3;key2=val4;key3=val5]
```

The web services I'm calling are published using PyWPS, and the query strings I'm using are valid if place in browser.

I've tried escaping all the value in the key-value-pairs:

```
e.g. "datainputs=[key1="+Uri.EscapeDataString("val1"), ...
```

I've also tried combinations of

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
```

and

```
HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode
```

I get errors such as: Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="key1"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but these url's work correctly in my browser so i suspect that I'm encoding them incorrectly.  I haven't been able to find any posts in which a single key-value-pair contains a list of key-value-pairs (i.e. datainputs=[key1=v1,v2,v2; ...etc)

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**  This is how I'm calling the web service

```
var targetUri = new Uri(uri);
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
        req.Method = method.ToUpper();
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseString;
```

Comment: How come this first scenario (the first code block) doesn't require escaping and it works properly.  Using the second code block throws an error "<ows:Exception exceptionCode="MissingParameterValue" locator="siteid" />".  I continue to get this error even if I escape the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Your '=' signs in "[key1=val1,val2,val3;key2=val4;key3=val5]" will need to be double escaped. Try escaping the value of datainputs and then escape the full URL.

Comment: I tried escaping everything inside "[" and  "]" then adding it to the rest of the query and escaping again, but this doesn't seem to work either.  I also tried escaping "[" and "]" with the rest of the datainputs, however this doesn't seem to work either.  I guess I don't quite understand how to escape a url.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result of what you just described?

Comment: @M.Babock Here is an example when only double escaping the values inside "[" and "]". `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/py-wps.cgi?service%3dwps%26version%3d1.0.0%26identifier%3drivermodel%26request%3dexecute%26datainputs%3d%5bsiteid%253d02169505%252c021695048%252c021695045%253bdatetime%253d2011-10-01_12%253a00%253bkey%253d%5d`